# SQL View DateTime

Tags: sql, datetime, view

I am trying to create a view from a table and append a new column to it which will give the user the date that it was recently updated... here is the create script that I am using and I am getting an error surrounding the syntax with 'datetime' - can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Create View [View].[WashingtonProspectiveBuyer] AS SELECT 
    [FirstName] AS FirstName, 
    [LastName] AS LastName, 
    CONCAT([AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City]) AS [Address], 
    [PostalCode] AS PostalCode,
    [Phone] AS Phone,
    [EmailAddress] AS EmailAddress,
    NULL As DateUpdated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()   
FROM dbo.ProspectiveBuyer  WHERE [StateProvinceCode] = 'WA'
```

Comment: You are confusing `create table` and `create view`.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `create table` and `create view`.  Perhaps you intend:

```
Create View [View].[WashingtonProspectiveBuyer] AS
    SELECT [FirstName] AS FirstName, 
           [LastName] AS LastName, 
           CONCAT([AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [City]) AS [Address], 
           [PostalCode] AS PostalCode,
           [Phone] AS Phone,
           [EmailAddress] AS EmailAddress,
           COALESCE(DateUpdated, GETDATE()  ) as  DateUpdated
    FROM dbo.ProspectiveBuyer 
    WHERE [StateProvinceCode] = 'WA';
```

`DEFAULT` syntax is how you declare columns.  It is used in `CREATE TABLE` statement, not in `SELECT` queries.